# TOTW - Alliteration questions?

Tags: discussion, topic-of-week

Could we do a week where we aim for alliterations as the question topic?

Pointless, but possibly fun or funny?

Comment: Sadly, serious solicitation seems to suggest subtraction.

Comment: Many manifestations of mildly mellifluous matters, may matter.

Comment: Nary a nitpick of a notorious notion?

Comment: Consider commenting?

Comment: Anyone assuming adverse affects, allocates in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If it isn't already obvious from the voting, I just don't think you strive for too much "pointless" fun running through your front page. It's going to [**set the tone of your site**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/) for a lot of folks for a long time to come.

But +1 for spirit points.

Comment: Mostly trying to have fun.  But seriously, Alliterated questions COULD theoretically work if done carefully.  Certainly challenging consideration.