# TOTW - Haiku questions?

Tags: discussion, topic-of-week

Like my question [TOTW - Alliteration questions?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/444/totw-alliteration-questions) could we consider a Topic of the Week where the questions are in the form of a haiku?

Just looking for a fun way to raise interest...

(Also since Meta points don't count, lets see how many downvotes I can generate, in good faith!)

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that I'm in opposition to this as well - many of the points in [Robert's answer](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/446/12) to your other question apply here:

> If it isn't already obvious from the voting, I just don't think you strive for too much "pointless" fun running through your front page. It's going to [**set the tone of your site**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/) for a lot of folks for a long time to come.
>
> But +1 for spirit points.

Imagine if you came to this site for the very first time, and found the front page full of Haiku questions - would you come back? It's rather hard to phrase a good question in the form of a Haiku - forget about answers. [Let's let mSO keep the Haiku thing.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208393/i-would-like-a-mug-please)

Comment: Bah humbug!  Worth a shot.